# Why some portion of the code of calling function in thread is not being executed

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I found this code in online and while running this code I found `print("This is awful {}".format(self))` this portion is not being executed. But if I
run without if like then both function are working (`self.connecting()`). I do not why this is happening. Can you please describe.

```
 class MyThread(Thread):
     def __init__(self, val):
        ''' Constructor. '''
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.val = val



 def run(self):
     for i in range(1, self.val):
         print('Value %d in thread %s' % (i, self.getName()))
         self.printing_fun()
         # Sleep for random time between 1 ~ 3 second
         #secondsToSleep = randint(1, 5)

         #time.sleep(secondsToSleep)

 def connecting(self):
     print "Establishing connection right now........."

 def printing_fun(self):
     # if i run like self.connecting() without previous if then all are 
     working fine.
     if  self.connecting():
      print("This is awefull {}".format(self)) 

# Run following code when the program starts
if __name__ == '__main__':
   # Declare objects of MyThread class
   myThreadOb1 = MyThread(4)
   myThreadOb1.setName('Thread 1')

   myThreadOb2 = MyThread(4)
   myThreadOb2.setName('Thread 2')



# Start running the threads!
   myThreadOb1.start()
   myThreadOb2.start()

   # Wait for the thre`enter code here`ads to finish...
   myThreadOb1.join()
   myThreadOb2.join()

   print('Main Terminating...')
```

Result:

> ```
> Value 1 in thread Thread 1
> Establishing connection right now.........
> Value 2 in thread Thread 1
> Establishing connection right now.........
> Value 3 in thread Thread 1
> Establishing connection right now.........
> Value 1 in thread Thread 2
> Establishing connection right now.........
> Value 2 in thread Thread 2
> Establishing connection right now.........
> Value 3 in thread Thread 2
> Establishing connection right now.........
> Main Terminating...
> ```

Comment: `self.connecting()` returns nothing so python returns `None`. Which is falsy: so condition is always false

Comment: Your  connecting method does not return a boolean, so it is always evaluated as 'False'

Comment: Ops, I got it..Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing to do with threading. Look at this code:

```
def connecting(self):
     print "Establishing connection right now........."

def printing_fun(self):
     # if i run like self.connecting() without previous if then all are 
     # working fine.
     if  self.connecting():
      print("This is awefull {}".format(self))
```

`self.connecting()` has no `return` statement, so python makes it return `None`.

And `if None:` condition is never met: it never enters the `if`

`connecting` is a stub of some connection procedure, but it's incorrectly implemented. To stub it properly you should just make it return something truthy:

```
def connecting(self):
     print("Establishing connection right now.........")
     return True
```